# "Poco/Un anno prima"

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Salve a tutti.
Sono un vecchio utente di questo forum e ho di ritornare con una nuova domanda.

A: È successo un anno/poco prima.

B: Questa storia si ripete da un'ora/poco prima.

Nel primo caso penso che "poco" e/o "un anno" siano degli avverbi con valore di misura/estensione e "prima" un avverbio, nel secondo sarei indeciso, perché mi verrebbe da attribuire due interpretazioni differenti, ossia la prima:

Un'ora/poco=sostantivi.

Prima=modificatore del nome/aggettivo.

La seconda, sulla base di "da molto lontano", sarebbe, per l'appunto (come la locuzione preposizionale "da lontano")la seguente:

Un'ora/poco= avverbi di misura.

Prima= avverbio di tempo.

È vero però che se la seconda frase fosse "questa storia si ripete da un'ora/poco prima di quell'avvenimento sconvolgente", non ci sarebbero dubbi, almeno per me, nell'interpretare in questo modo:

Un'ora/poco= sostantivo.

Prima di= modificatore del sostantivo/sintagma preposizionale.

Nella frase invece  "questo è successo un'ora/poco prima di quell'avvenimento" non saprei come analizzare la frase, cioè se la preposizione "prima di" funga da modificatore di "un'ora/poco" intesi come sostantivo o se bisogna intendete "un'ora/poco" come avverbi e prima di come semplice preposizione.

Quali sono le vostre considerazioni in merito? Quali sono le interpretazioni corrette?

Buona serata

Comment: Analizzerei come “È successo poco (tempo) prima” con “tempo” sottinteso; complemento di tempo.

Comment: Trovo anche che “questa storia si ripete da poco prima” non abbia molto senso.

Comment: Sarebbe meglio scrivere frasi complete in alternativa, evitando la barra che è ambigua.

Comment: @egreg: la vedo simile a "questa storia succede e risuccede costantemente dall'anno scorso" cosa c'è di sbagliato a livello grammaticale? Magari cambiando un po' il verbo avrebbe più senso: " Questa storia ha iniziato a ripetersi giornalmente da poco prima, ossia dalla settimana precedente a quel particolare incontro".  Ho corretto. Grazie Egreg